# CRUD with AngularJS and Play

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, playframework, coffeescript

I am building a new project with AngularJS, Play Framework and MongoDB. My code is based on the modern-web-template from Typesafe Activator. At the moment I can Create new Objects and show them in a list. The next step is editing an Object, which is where I have my problem.

In my Category List I have the following link in my table:

```
<td><a ng-href="/#/categories/edit/{{cat.category}}">edit</a></td>
```

my app.coffee (Angular.js routung):

```
angular.module('myApp.routeConfig', ['ngRoute'])
    .config ($routeProvider) ->
        $routeProvider
        .when('/categories/edit/:category', {
                templateUrl: '/assets/partials/categories/edit.html'
                controller: '/assets/javascripts/categories/EditCategoryCtrl'
            })
```

the *EditCategoryCtrl.coffee*:

```
class EditCategoryCtrl

constructor: (@$log, @$location,  @CategoryService, @category) ->
    @category = @CategoryService.findCategoryByCategory(category) // should load the category, but the constructor doesn't get invoked (see below)


editCategory: (category: String) ->
    @CategoryService.editCategory(@category)
    .then(
        (data) =>
            @category = data
            @$location.path("/categories")
        ,
        (error) =>
            @$log.error "Unable to edit Category: #{error}"
        )
controllersModule.controller('EditCategoryCtrl', EditCategoryCtrl)
```

my play *routes* file:

```
GET     /categories/edit/:category  @controllers.Categories.findByCategory(category: String)
PUT     /categories/edit/:category  @controllers.Categories.edit(category: String)
```

as stated above my Constructor in *EditCategoryCtrl.coffee* doesn't get invoked and the following error is thrown in the javascript console:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument '/assets/javascripts/categories/EditCategoryCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.13/ng/areq?p0=%2Fassets%2Fjavascripts%2Fcategories%2FEditCategoryCtrl&p1=not%20a                 nanunction%2C%20got%20undefined
```

I hope I incleded all necessary code (if not, please let me know). Hope anyone can point me in the right direction. Thank you!

**edit**
my `CategoryService.coffee`:

```
findCategoryByCategory: (category) ->
        @$log.debug "findCategoryByCategory()"
        @$log.debug category
        deferred = @$q.defer()

        @$http.get("/categories/edit/:category", category)
        .success((data, status, headers) =>
                @$log.info("Successfully loaded Category - status #{status}")
                deferred.resolve(data)
            )
        .error((data, status, headers) =>
                @$log.error("Failed to load Category - status #{status}")
                deferred.reject(data);
            )
        deferred.promise
```

**edit2**

with the help of Valentin I can now load the Category Object as JSON and log it to my console:

```
"Successfully loaded Category - status 200"
Object { category: "test", description: "test", status: Object }
```

But still nothing gets rendered to my view `edit.html`:

```
<div ng-controller="EditCategoryCtrl as ecc"><!-- other stuff --> 
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="category" id="category" ng-model="ecc.category.category">
```

this seems not to work. Is the problem maybe that this gets rendered before the async query is finished? If yes, how could I prevent this?

Comment: I'm not a CoffeeScript specialist, but are you sure about using classes to define a controller?

Comment: neither am I, but the same code works for my CreateCategoryCtrl `class CreateCategoryCtrl
    constructor: (@$log, @$location,  @CategoryService) ->
        @$log.debug "constructing CreateCategoryController"
        @category = {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`category` does not get dependency-injected because it is a URL param.

You can retrieve it from the `$routeParams` service, e.g:

```
controllersModule.controller('EditCategoryCtrl',
  ['$log', '$location', 'CategoryService', '$routeParams', '$scope',
    ($log, $location, CategoryService, $routeParams, $scope) ->
      CategoryService.findCategoryByCategory($routeParams.category)
      .then((category) ->
        $scope.category = category
      )
  ])
```

or use a `resolve` in the route declaration, e.g :

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/categories/edit/:category', {
    templateUrl: '/assets/partials/categories/edit.html'
    controller: '/assets/javascripts/categories/EditCategoryCtrl'
    resolve: {
      category: ['$routeParams','CategoryService', ($routeParams, CategoryService) -> CategoryService.findCategoryByCategory($routeParams.category)]
    }
  })
```

If `findCategoryByCategory` is asynchronous, you will most likely want to use the second approach.

Finally, your object does not get rendered because it is never exported into the `$scope` (see above). Here is what your HTML should look like :

```
<div ng-controller="EditCategoryCtrl"><!-- other stuff --> 
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="category" id="category" ng-model="category.category">
```

You should really not see a controller as a class, rather a function into which services and the `$scope` objects get injected, letting you bind HTML and services with display logic.

Comment: this does work. at least now I have my correct `category` in my `CategoryService.findCategoryByCategory` but now I get `"Error: parsed is undefined` in the line (output from JS console):

`this.$http.get("/categories/edit/:category", category).success(function(data, status, headers) {`

Comment: You can't call `$http.get` that way. Replace `:category` with `category` by hand in your URL string. See here : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get

Comment: with `@$http.get("/categories/edit/" + category)` I got a bit further (see my second edit of my original post). Unfotunatly I'm not quite there yet. thanks for your help so far!

Comment: unfortunately I get the error `"Error: this.$scope is undefined` now. I tried both your variations, but I end up always with this error.

Comment: That must be my bad CoffeeScript. If you want, I can show you how to do it not using a class at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59064/discussion-between-valentin-waeselynck-and-markus).